# Getting first values from objects instead of getting that was chosen by user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

Function `holdAnswer` has to change the property `isChosen` from false to true and mutate state, adding new value to the questions. Then function `checkAnswers` has to find answers that user has chosen and compare if the selected answers have property `isCorrect`, which has to be true. And if `isCorrect` is true and `isChosen` is true, function `checkAnswers` has to change the score count. It keeps showing me only the first answers, no matter what the user chose. Why it doesn't show me the answers which user chose?

Please take a look at [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-quiz-app-wilvqf?file=/src/App.js)

App.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import QuestionSet from "./components/QuestionSet";
import Answers from "./components/Answers";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

function App() {
  const [isQuesLoaded, setIsQuesLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);

  async function startQuiz() {
    try {
      setIsQuesLoaded(!isQuesLoaded);
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=12&difficulty=easy&type=multiple"
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      const allQuestions = data.results;
      const listOfQuestions = allQuestions.map((item) => {
        const allAnswers = [
          {
            id: nanoid(),
            isCorrect: false,
            isChosen: false,
            answer: item.incorrect_answers[0]
          },
          {
            id: nanoid(),
            isCorrect: false,
            isChosen: false,
            answer: item.incorrect_answers[1]
          },
          {
            id: nanoid(),
            isCorrect: false,
            isChosen: false,
            answer: item.incorrect_answers[2]
          },
          {
            id: nanoid(),
            isCorrect: true,
            isChosen: false,
            answer: item.correct_answer
          }
        ];
        return {
          id: nanoid(),
          question: item.question,
          answers: allAnswers
        };
      });
      setQuestions(listOfQuestions);
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err.message);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }

  function holdAnswer(questionId, answerId) {
    console.log({ questionId, answerId });
    setQuestions((prevQuestion) =>
      prevQuestion.map((question) =>
        question.id === questionId
          ? {
            ...question,
            answers: question.answers.map((answer) =>
              answer.id === answerId
                ? { ...answer, isChosen: !answer.isChosen }
                : answer
            )
          }
          : question
      )
    );
  }

  function checkAnswers() {
    let correctCount = 0;
    questions.forEach(question => {
      const selectedAnswer = question.answers.find(answer => answer.answer.id === answer.answer.isChosen);
      if (selectedAnswer.isCorrect) correctCount += 1;
      setScore(correctCount);
      console.log(correctCount);
      console.log(selectedAnswer);
    })
  }

  const questionElm = questions.map((question, index) => {
    return (
      <section key={index}>
        <QuestionSet question={question.question} key={question.id} />
        <Answers
          answers={question.answers}
          isChosen={question.answers.isChosen}
          holdAnswer={(answerId) => holdAnswer(question.id, answerId)}
        />
      </section>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {!isQuesLoaded ? (
        <main>
          <h1 className="title-app">Quizzical</h1>
          <p className="desc-app">Some description if needed</p>
          <button className="btn" onClick={startQuiz}>
            Start Quiz
          </button>
        </main>
      ) : (
        <main className="quest-box">
          {loading && <div>Loading data...</div>}
          {error && <div>{`There is a problem fetchning data = ${error}`}</div>}
          <section className="quest-content">{questionElm}</section>

          <button className="answer-btn" onClick={checkAnswers}>Check Answers</button>
        </main>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answers.js

```
  function Answer(props) {
  const styles = {
    backgroundColor: props.answer.isChosen ? "#D6DBF5" : "transparent"
  };
  return (
    <div
      className="answer-div"
      style={styles}
      id={props.answer.id}
      onClick={() => props.holdAnswer(props.answer.id)}
    >
      <p>{props.answer.answer}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function Answers(props) {
  return (
    <section className="answer-container">
      {props.answers.map((answer) => (
        <Answer holdAnswer={props.holdAnswer} answer={answer} key={answer.id} />
      ))}
    </section>
  );
}
```

QuestionSet.js

```
export default function QuestionSet(props) {
  return (
    <section className="quest" key={props.id}>
      <p>{props.question}</p>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing that I'm seeing is that you are passing `holdAnswer` function down via props on a wrong way

You need to change to something this (Simplified for convenience):

App.js

```js
<Answers
    answers={question.answers}
    isChosen={question.answers.isChosen}
    holdAnswer={ 
        holdAnswer(question.id, answerId) // Telling what to execute from here (Without the param on the arrow function)
    }
/>
```

Answers.js

```js
<Answer holdAnswer={
        props.holdAnswer // passing the whole function knowing what to execute
    }
/>
```

Answer

```js
<button onClick={() => 
        props.holdAnswer // knowing what to do from App.js
    } 
/>
```

#### Or you can do it like this:

App.js

```js
<Answers
    answers={question.answers}
    isChosen={question.answers.isChosen}
    holdAnswer={
        holdAnswer // passing the whole function to execute it in another component
    }
/>
```

Answers.js

```js
<Answer holdAnswer={
        props.holdAnswer  // passing the whole function to execute it in another
    }
/>
```

Answer

```js
<button onClick={() => 
        props.holdAnswer(props.param1, props.param2) // executing the function here passing the parameters
    } 
/>
```

Not sure if this is going to fix your problem but at least it can simplify it.